# Visual Studio Windows Project Open With Visual Studio Mac

Tags: visual-studio

Since the configurations and structure of projects created in Visual Studio(Windows) differ from projects created in Visual Studio(Mac).

Is it possible for a project created in Visual Studio(Windows) to be opened and modified in Visual Studio(Mac) and vice versa.

Comment: Will you explain more how the structure differ? And also what kind of project you want to open?

Comment: VS-windows uses config files for configurations while VS-mac uses some other mechanism and I want to open and modify in VS-Mac a WEB API project developed in VS-Windows.

Comment: Yes, with the newer version of Visual Studio you can open the project created in Windows on Mac.